# Bind JSON data from Controller and display name in the View

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

My JSON string in developer tool network tab is:

```
[{\"id\":\"904c7ccd-d568-40ca-a3ab-1d097d555f52\",\"name\":\"BPANDE2\",\"actualName\":\"Pande, Bhavana (B.V.)\",\"displayName\":\"Pande, Bhavana (B.V.) (BPANDE2)\",\"email\":\"bpande2@abc.com\",\"deleted\":false,\"deletedDate\":0,\"authenticationRealm\":\"f4191d4b-4331-4637-af6f-c89781687bf6\",\"isLockedOut\":false,\"lastLoginDate\":1521144701377,\"isDeletable\":true,\"groups\":[{\"id\":\"7862c275-8eb2-42cf-895c-214c2826a0b8\",\"name\":\"config_viewer\",\"enabled\":true}]}]
```

My Controller Code is

```
public class Login
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool enabled { get; set; }
}
public class LoginDetails
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string actualName { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public bool deleted { get; set; }
    public int deletedDate { get; set; }
    public string authenticationRealm { get; set; }
    public bool isLockedOut { get; set; }
    public long lastLoginDate { get; set; }
    public bool isDeletable { get; set; }
    public List<Login> groups { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
  //Covert JSON to .net object using Deserialize method
            var jsonString = **The json string is displayed as above in "my json string in developer tool network tab is:"**
    JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<LoginDetails> listName = (List<LoginDetails>)javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString,typeof(List<LoginDetails>)); 

    foreach (LoginDetails login in listName)
    {
        Response.Write("Welcome" + "<br/>");
        Response.Write("" + login.displayName + "<br/>");
    }
}
```

My View Code is:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
Welcome **@Model.displayName**
```

I want to display the displayName in the View but the "@Model.displayName" doesn't seem to work. Could you help me how can I use ViewData property to display the name in the View?or may be some other property in the view?

Comment: You might return `listName` or `login` object be a razor model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, that's not how you should use MVC.

Your Action `Index` should `return View(model);` so that your view can be rendered correctly. And your View should state the type of the model.

In ASP.Net MVC it is unusual to write directly to the response stream and definitely wrong here.

Change `Index` to

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var jsonString = « The JSON string from below »
    JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<LoginDetails> listName = (List<LoginDetails>)javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString,typeof(List<LoginDetails>)); 

    return View(listName.First());
}
```

Also change your View to

```
@model LoginDetails
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

Welcome @Model.displayName
```

For reference I've added the formatted JSON here

```
[
  {
    "id": "904c7ccd-d568-40ca-a3ab-1d097d555f52",
    "name": "BPANDE2",
    "actualName": "Pande, Bhavana (B.V.)",
    "displayName": "Pande, Bhavana (B.V.) (BPANDE2)",
    "email": "bpande2@abc.com",
    "deleted": false,
    "deletedDate": 0,
    "authenticationRealm": "f4191d4b-4331-4637-af6f-c89781687bf6",
    "isLockedOut": false,
    "lastLoginDate": 1521144701377,
    "isDeletable": true,
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": "7862c275-8eb2-42cf-895c-214c2826a0b8",
        "name": "config_viewer",
        "enabled": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```